# Getting index of a clicked element

Tags: dom, indexing

Hi I have this code. I need to get the 0 based index of the clicked element.

This is my code. I always get -1 as the index.
Ideally clicking first link would print 0 and second would print 1.
I am using jquery 1.3.2. JavaScript code is fine too.

What I am missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleClick(id) {         
         var par = document.getElementById('par'+id);         
         alert('Index= ' + $('#clips').index(par));
      }
</script>

<div id="clips" style="clear:both">                                                   
         <div id="par30" class="alb rc32">
            <div class="fl rc32 thm">
               <a id="30" onclick="handleClick(30);">Link 1</a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="par40" class="alb rc32">
            <div class="fl rc32 thm">
               <a id="40" onclick="handleClick(40);">Link 2</a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="par50" class="alb rc32">
            <div class="fl rc32 thm">
               <a id="50" onclick="handleClick(50);">Link 3</a>
            </div>
         </div>                                         
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the index function wrong.

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleClick(id) {         
         var par = document.getElementById('par'+id);         
         alert('Index= ' + $('#clips > div').index(par));
      }
</script>
```

see http://api.jquery.com/index/

> If .index() is called on a collection
>   of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index()
>   returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element
>   relative to the original collection.

Comment: Sometimes its hard to be the first answer!  I changed the selector used from '#clips' to '#clips > div' and then called index using that collection passing in the particular object you want the index of.  Dr Rob's answer is also good.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleClick(id) {
        var $par = $('#par' + id);
        alert($par.index());
    }
```

```
    <div id="clips" style="clear:both">                                                   
     <div id="par30" class="alb rc32">
        <div class="fl rc32 thm">
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="30" onclick="handleClick(30);">Link 1</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="par40" class="alb rc32">
        <div class="fl rc32 thm">
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="40" onclick="handleClick(40);">Link 2</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="par50" class="alb rc32">
        <div class="fl rc32 thm">
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="50" onclick="handleClick(50);">Link 3</a>
        </div>
     </div>                                         
  </div>
```

Comment: You were too fast for me.  :)  This site seems competitive when it comes to answering things fast!  That's good though.

Comment: lol - thanks - can you please mark this as the answer if it is correct.